# Axios POST cannot trigger after 5 POST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have a problem with Axios POST in ReactJS which after 5 commands sent with Axios to NodeJS, sixth cannot POST any commands.

```
await axios.post(`/sensors/sensors/jamming`, { sensorId });
```

Also, I tried to put timeout to axios to block the response but it didnot work.
It would be grateful if anyone can help me.

```
await axios.post(`/sensors/sensors/jamming`, { sensorId }, {timeout: 1000});
```

Comment: Hey Ramin! did you check the backend if request is coming there and not fullfilled or frontend(react) is not sending sending sixth request ? Further please add some more 
 code of backend/frontend where the problem begins.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I should add some code in backend.
Actually I add below code in Nodejs.
res.send(200).
React JS waiting for the request from Nodejs